# Set range of numerical values for a text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a text field that must take numerical value of a specific range only, say m to n. I have gone through many articles but they all just say how to set maximum length for the text field. But I need to set the text field so that it takes values only of the range, say 23 to 103. I managed to make sure that that the text field only takes numerical values by setting the keyboard type to number pad. Someone please help.

Comment: I am trying to develop an iOS app.

Comment: if you want to set minimum value as 23 then what happend when type 2 on the textfield means what you are expecting?

Comment: ok.. you got a point there. But I badly need to set a higher limit. leave the lower limit.

Comment: You can do that in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` too. Just limit your inputs to the numbers 0 to 9 and add additional logic for the "up to 103" stuff. Also using the number keypad does not limit any inputs. You can still copy and paste or use an external keyboard.

Comment: So can't I use 0 to 103 with `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`?

Comment: This is not an XCode question.

Comment: @Amar: I wanted to know if there is anything that can be done using Xcode or programatically to set the limit. So it is an Xcode question.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT The tag you are looking for is Interface Builder. Xcode is a very broad tag for this question.

Comment: @Amar No. This is neither a question about Interface Builder nor Xcode.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Agreed

Comment: The interface builder tag was appropriate if what the OP is asking was doable with interface builder. For example if he was programming on OS X. he could drop a text field with a number formatter in the xib window and set the maximum/minimum value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the value when the user finished editing the textfield.

Set the textField's delegate to your view controller and then:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *stringValue = textField.text;
    NSInteger integer = [stringValue intValue];
    if (integer <23 || integer > 103)
        // You can make the text red here for example
        return NO;
    else 
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is, if the upper limit is 103, then the user must not be able to type 104.

Comment: That's why I return NO in the textFieldShouldEndEditing. He cannot stop editing the textfield until he enters a valid value.

Comment: Well i think the logic should be in textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: method.

Answer (score 2):

You typically achieve this by using a custom number formatter that has a minimum/maximum acceptable value, like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter= [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.allowsFloats= NO;
formatter.maximum= @103;
formatter.minimum= @23;
```

Then allow the user to return only if the formatter returns a valid number:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{ 
    return [formatter numberFromString: textField.text]!= nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
If you want to set range for a particular textfield.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

{

```
if(textField == self.txtMobileNumber )
{
    if (textField.text.length >= 10 && range.length == 0)
        return NO;
}
}
```